# Activate youtube auto translation using query parameters in the url

Tags: youtube, query-string

Is it possible to force activate youtube auto translation using query parameters in the url? I tried this but it's not working

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xxxx&scc_lang_pref=en&cc_load_policy=1